# @font-face not embedding in IE8 and under

Tags: font-face

for some reason the font is not rendering in IE 8 and under. I've applied the IE fix (.eot?#iefix) which always has worked but for some reason it's not this time. Anybody know what's going wrong or have had an issue like this as well? Here's what I have:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'rrb-main';
src: url('./assets/rrb-main.eot');
src: url('./assets/rrb-main.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./assets/rrb-main.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./assets/rrb-main.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11386333/638254 regarding where in the DOM you put the `@font-face`

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes around your tags like so:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "rrb-main";
src: url("./assets/rrb-main.eot");
src: url("./assets/rrb-main.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("./assets/rrb-main.woff") format("woff"),
     url("./assets/rrb-main.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I don't know why but sometimes that works. This tag should work since you have the EOT version of the font.