# @font-face crashes IE8

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, crash, font-face

I just installed the fonts Aller Regular and Aller bold on my site via @font-face (generated by [fontsquirrel.com](http://fontsquirrel.com)).

Here is the CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerRegular';
    src: url('library/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#AllerRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerBold';
    src: url('aller_bd-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.svg#AllerBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

This is working fine when I use ether of the fonts in firefox, however when I use IE8 the webpage crashes attempts to reopen and crashes again. A live example can be found at http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/

Does anyone know what's causing this madness?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem a while ago, and after some debugging I found that the crash was because of the `@font-face` (which in my case was included as a separate stylesheet called fonts.css) was rendered inside `<head>`. IE8 has a problem with this, but works just fine when I moved the rendering to just inside `<body>`.

Try this:

```
<head>
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- The rest of your page here -->
</body>
```

This renders the fonts stylesheet within your head if the browser is newer than IE8. If the browser is IE8, it renders it just inside your body.

Note: You may have to adjust the conditional comments if you're supporting IE7 or older.

Answer (score 4):

IE8 seems to prefer double quotes. This fixed unstyled text on first load for me, might fix crashes for you.

Kudos to the guy here, which solved my problem: [@font-face not embedding in IE8 and under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033353/font-face-not-embedding-in-ie8-and-under)

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issure developing page with custom fonts. IE8 crashed. I fixed it by placing IE8 font-face declaration BEFORE any other font-face declarations. I.E:

```
<!-- Custom .eot fonts for IE8 -->
<!-- IE8 fonts should load before other font-face declarations to avoid IE8 crash  -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pub/stylesheets/fonts-ie8.css" />     
<![endif]-->

<!-- Custom .woff fonts -->
<link href="/pub/stylesheets/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
```