# Web Fonts Not Loading IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, webfonts

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I have just converted a set of fonts using Font2Web and I have attached the following code to my css to render my fonts required, as I normally would.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Bold';
    src: url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold/fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold/fonts/Gotham-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold/fonts/Gotham-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold/fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Bold/fonts/Gotham-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham Medium';
    src: url('../fonts/Gotham-Medium/fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Gotham-Medium/fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Medium/fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Medium/fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Gotham-Medium/fonts/Gotham-Medium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The result is that my font gets rendered well on Chrome, Safari, Firefox but IE8 flops and does not load the required fonts at all.

My guess could be the converter i was using might have issues with the EOT files, unless if there is anything else, any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It says

```
 In Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, only one URL value is supported.
```

You are giving many URL's, so that might be the problem.

Comment: The first `src` rule has just one URL and should thus be used by IE 8, so this suggests that the .eot file is indeed broken, as suspected in the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That is true, that first .eot file is broken. But what truly breaks on IE 8 is its behaviour that only takes first url, not multiple unlike modern browsers. Putting the .eot file that works in first url will fix it.

Comment: @user568109 Thanks for your answer. I'll have a check tonight. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recall an IE8 issue relating to @font-face where rendering blocks of

```
@font-face{
    ...
}
```

in the head of a document (or in files referenced from the document head) could glitch and not display properly, the bug work around was to place those css blocks of @font-face in the body of a document.

hope this help

[see this question for additional details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294206/font-face-crashes-ie8)

Comment: Hey Joe thanks for your answer, I'll have a check of it tonight. :)