# Loading webfont files completely hangs IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webfonts

I have come across a very strange loading issue with IE8 - whenever I do certain steps on a page, IE8 simply hangs and tries to load webfonts (.eot file) forever.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use IE8 (problem exists on both Microsoft's IE8 testing Windows 7 VM in Windows and in Windows XP).
2. Open http://kopterid.ee
3. Click on "Tooted" link
4. Click on "Esileht" link
5. Reload the page (F5)

This is what I get (the page doesn't refresh, simply hangs or is blank):
[image: IE 8 message when it has hung]

CSS that includes the webfont:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  src: url("typefaces/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot");
  src: url("typefaces/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("typefaces/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("typefaces/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("typefaces/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url("typefaces/icomoon.eot");
  src: url("typefaces/icomoon.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("typefaces/icomoon.woff") format('woff'), url("typefaces/icomoon.ttf") format('truetype'), url("typefaces/icomoon.svg#icomoon") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
}
```

I have tried disabling all plugins, gzip compression etc, but the problem still remains.

The site uses Wordpress WooCommerce plugin with Mystile theme.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this trick: [@font-face crashes IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294206/font-face-crashes-ie8#11386333) ? It worked for me in the past. ( I haven't tried for your specific situation, but it will probably work )

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Also found that post a couple of days ago. Will test it!