# IE8 and CSS @font-face crashes the browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I see there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294206/font-face-crashes-ie8) for the same issue but none of the suggestions are working for me. I'm loading a few weights of a text font and a custom icon font using this syntax:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "proxima_nova_rgregular";
  src: url("../vendor/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot");
  src: url("../vendor/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../vendor/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../vendor/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("../vendor/fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.svg#proximanova-regular-webfont") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

About 80% of the time this will completely crash the browser. I'm using this with bootstrap as well but can't find anything that would indicate an incompatibility. I've tried loading with javascript, before the closing body tag, and about a hundred other ways.

The event viewer shows a crash on mshtml.dll

```
Faulting application name: iexplore.exe, version: 8.0.7601.18715, time stamp: 0x54b3297e
Faulting module name: mshtml.dll, version: 8.0.7601.18715, time stamp: 0x54b334da
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000d87e0
Faulting process id: 0x25c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d04d3634afbed0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll
Report Id: ac43aaa2-bb80-11e4-9a74-000c29491be4
```

I'm completely stumped here and everything I've tried is leading me nowhere - any points in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that encounters this issue, in my case it came down to some bad markup right before the closing `</body>` tag. Scouring through the masterpage and removing block by block eventually resolved it.